# ElasticSearch 2.1 Java Example

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have been trying to write a Simple ElasticSearch Java search using some of the examples given on the websites. I have not implemented Spring or other frameworks. Most elastic-search examples appear to be incomplete code samples. Some of the websites I referenced are..

[ElasticSearch Official Website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/2.1/java-search.html)

[Spring ElasticSearch](https://dzone.com/articles/elasticsearch-java-api)

My goal is to create a blog with some fully working examples. Many appear to reference **ImmutableSettings** class which does not appear to be on the list of classes. Even the most basic example "www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/getting-started-with-elasticsearch.html" references the ImmutableSettings which doesn't compile. Maybe I'm missing a Jar file.

My question is: Is there a fully working ElasticSearch 2.1 Java stand-alone example that I can get up and running without complex frameworks.

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImmutableSettings is not available in elasticsearch versions greater than 2.0

If you are using it for transport client creation you can use

TransportClient transportClient = TransportClient.builder().build();

```
        transportClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
```